# Custom Boolean Field Retrieve

Tags: soql, soap-api, php, enterprise, boolean

I'm currently only able to retrieve non-boolean columns from a SOQL query when using the  SforceEnterpriseClient. In the below query Columns1 and Column2 fail to return data to me.

```
SELECT Column1__c, Column2__c, Column3__c, Column4__c, Column5__c, Column6__c
FROM Table__c
where Column5__c >= 2016-09-29
```

If I execute the same query in WorkBench it works fine so I think it must be a setting I'm missing. Column1 and Column2 are booleans.

Full code usage:

```
try {
    $salesforce = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
    $salesforce->createConnection('salesforce_connector/soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
    $salesforce->login('user', 'pass');
    $query = 'SELECT Column1__c, Column2__c, Column3__c, Column4__c, Column5__c, Column6__c
    FROM Table__c
    where Column3__c >= ' . date('Y-m-d');
    $options = new QueryOptions(2000);
    $salesforce->setQueryOptions($options);
    $response = $salesforce->query($query);
    die(print_r($response));
```

Response (Single example):

```
[1878] => SObject Object
            (
                [type] => 
                [fields] => 
                [Column3__c] => 2016-12-31
                [Column4__c] => 0022000000abcHcAAI
                [Column5__c] => 43892
                [Column6__c] => 2013-06-01
            )
```

Comment: Has the SforceEnterpriseClient been updated more recently than 2009? https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_11.0_Getting_Started ... after looking, it appears the Force.com Toolkit for PHP is currently at v20 is this the version you're using? https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit

Comment: Yes, our `SforceBaseClient.php` has `protected $version = '20.0';`.

Comment: Apologies for pointing out the obvious, but we all miss the obvious sometimes: Are you using the same user credentials in your PHP and Workbench test? If not, it could be worth checking the field-level security.

Comment: @Aidan For `Field-level security` it is set to `visible` for all users. The only other option there is `read-only` though so maybe I'm looking at the wrong place? I'm in `Custom Field Definition Detail`.

Comment: Again, sorry to be going through the obvious, but I'm pretty sure there's no fundamental problem with getting booleans from PHP toolkit. Do you have the latest version of the Enterprise WSDL i.e. does it have those fields you're missing included in it?

Comment: @Aidan Yup the WSDL has the fields in it `<element name="Column1__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>` and `<element name="Column2__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>`. We have the latest version of the tool kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that there is something wrong with enterprise WSDL.
possible options to check are:

- Check if the WSDL is latest or not
- Check the path of WSDL - its possible that you may be checking at X path and code is referring Y path.

If non of above help to identify issue then next thing to try is replace Enterprise WSDL with Partner WSDL and run your code.

Comment: The paths are correct. The `createConnection` is an absolute path in deployment. I've updated the Enterprise WSDL to one downloaded today. The issue remains the same though. I'm not see the `Partner WSDL`

Comment: After adding 2 new fields to the object, regenerating another WSDL, then using `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");`, this now works. So seems WSDL was somehow related, not sure why the first update didnt work though.